# Show column names of multiple-colum index via JDBC

Tags: java, database, jdbc

Does anyone know how to get the column names of an index that spans multiple columns (see `SQL`) via `JDBC` ? I do know how to get all index columns (see code), but this way I cannot see which columns are linked to a single index.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `test2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `test1` (`test1`,`test2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

DatabaseMetaData md = connection.getMetaData(); // assumed that connection exists
ResultSet rs = md.getIndexInfo(null, dbSchema, "foo", true, false);
while (rs.next()) {
    String columnName = rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a multi-column index multiple entries will be returned in ResultSet with the same INDEX_NAME but different COLUMN_NAME

Answer (score 0):

A general word of advice: Look at the [Java API javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) if you want to see if some information is available before asking a question on Stackoverflow. If you look at the Javadoc of [`DatabaseMetaData.getIndexInfo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getIndexInfo%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean%29), you will see that the returned resultset contains a lot more columns than just `COLUMN_NAME`.

For your purposes, you should also look at `INDEX_NAME` and maybe `ORDINAL_POSITION` (if you want to know the order of columns inside the index). For a compound index, the `ResultSet` contains more than one row (ie one row per column in the index).

My answer does assume that your JDBC driver correctly implements and returns all required information.