# JDBC: Unable to get composite index for my table

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, composite-index

I am trying to list all the indexes for all the tables in my DB (using a generic solution which is not specific to an RDBMS)

To test out my solution, I have 2 tables in an MS SQL Server DB `tempdb`

- Stores
- Staffs

Each table has a PK and the `staffs` table also have a Unique key column called `email`.
There is a composite index on the `stores` table on `store_id, store_name`.

Following are the indexes (screenshots from DBeaver)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The code snippet is as follows

```
.
.
.
System.out.println("**********************************************************");
System.out.println("schema >>> "+schema);
System.out.println("table >>> "+table);
ResultSet indexValues = tableMeta.getIndexInfo(null, null, table, true, false);
while (indexValues.next()) {
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = indexValues.getMetaData();  
    String idxName = indexValues.getString("INDEX_NAME");
    System.out.println("=====================================================");
    System.out.println("rs1 >>> "+indexValues.getString(1));
    System.out.println("rs2 >>> "+indexValues.getString(2));
    System.out.println("rs3 >>> "+indexValues.getString(3));
    System.out.println("rs4 >>> "+indexValues.getString(4));
    System.out.println("rs5 >>> "+indexValues.getString(5));
    System.out.println("rs6 >>> "+indexValues.getString(6));
    System.out.println("rsmd >>> "+rsmd.getColumnCount());
    System.out.println("INDEX_NAME >>> "+indexValues.getString("INDEX_NAME"));
    System.out.println("INDEX_QUALIFIER >>> "+indexValues.getString("INDEX_QUALIFIER"));
    System.out.println("NON_UNIQUE >>> "+indexValues.getBoolean("NON_UNIQUE"));
    System.out.println("TYPE >>> "+indexValues.getShort("TYPE"));
    System.out.println("ORDINAL_POSITION >>> "+indexValues.getString("ORDINAL_POSITION"));
    System.out.println("COLUMN_NAME >>> "+indexValues.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
    System.out.println("ASC_OR_DESC >>> "+indexValues.getString("ASC_OR_DESC"));
    System.out.println("FILTER_CONDITION >>> "+indexValues.getString("FILTER_CONDITION"));
    System.out.println("TABLE_SCHEM >>> "+indexValues.getString("TABLE_SCHEM"));
    System.out.println("TABLE_CAT >>> "+indexValues.getString("TABLE_CAT"));
    System.out.println("=====================================================");

}
```

The output is as follows (the compound/composite index is not returned)

```
**********************************************************
schema >>> dbo
table >>> stores
=====================================================
rs1 >>> tempdb
rs2 >>> dbo
rs3 >>> stores
rs4 >>> null
rs5 >>> null
rs6 >>> null
rsmd >>> 13
INDEX_NAME >>> null
INDEX_QUALIFIER >>> null
NON_UNIQUE >>> false
TYPE >>> 0
ORDINAL_POSITION >>> null
COLUMN_NAME >>> null
ASC_OR_DESC >>> null
FILTER_CONDITION >>> null
TABLE_SCHEM >>> dbo
TABLE_CAT >>> tempdb
=====================================================
=====================================================
rs1 >>> tempdb
rs2 >>> dbo
rs3 >>> stores
rs4 >>> 0
rs5 >>> stores
rs6 >>> PK__stores__A2F2A30C0F20F60B
rsmd >>> 13
INDEX_NAME >>> PK__stores__A2F2A30C0F20F60B
INDEX_QUALIFIER >>> stores
NON_UNIQUE >>> false
TYPE >>> 1
ORDINAL_POSITION >>> 1
COLUMN_NAME >>> store_id
ASC_OR_DESC >>> A
FILTER_CONDITION >>> null
TABLE_SCHEM >>> dbo
TABLE_CAT >>> tempdb
=====================================================
**********************************************************
schema >>> dbo
table >>> staffs
=====================================================
rs1 >>> tempdb
rs2 >>> dbo
rs3 >>> staffs
rs4 >>> null
rs5 >>> null
rs6 >>> null
rsmd >>> 13
INDEX_NAME >>> null
INDEX_QUALIFIER >>> null
NON_UNIQUE >>> false
TYPE >>> 0
ORDINAL_POSITION >>> null
COLUMN_NAME >>> null
ASC_OR_DESC >>> null
FILTER_CONDITION >>> null
TABLE_SCHEM >>> dbo
TABLE_CAT >>> tempdb
=====================================================
=====================================================
rs1 >>> tempdb
rs2 >>> dbo
rs3 >>> staffs
rs4 >>> 0
rs5 >>> staffs
rs6 >>> PK__staffs__1963DD9CCB589A48
rsmd >>> 13
INDEX_NAME >>> PK__staffs__1963DD9CCB589A48
INDEX_QUALIFIER >>> staffs
NON_UNIQUE >>> false
TYPE >>> 1
ORDINAL_POSITION >>> 1
COLUMN_NAME >>> staff_id
ASC_OR_DESC >>> A
FILTER_CONDITION >>> null
TABLE_SCHEM >>> dbo
TABLE_CAT >>> tempdb
=====================================================
=====================================================
rs1 >>> tempdb
rs2 >>> dbo
rs3 >>> staffs
rs4 >>> 0
rs5 >>> staffs
rs6 >>> UQ__staffs__AB6E6164E6F8EDB6
rsmd >>> 13
INDEX_NAME >>> UQ__staffs__AB6E6164E6F8EDB6
INDEX_QUALIFIER >>> staffs
NON_UNIQUE >>> false
TYPE >>> 3
ORDINAL_POSITION >>> 1
COLUMN_NAME >>> email
ASC_OR_DESC >>> A
FILTER_CONDITION >>> null
TABLE_SCHEM >>> dbo
TABLE_CAT >>> tempdb
=====================================================
```

I've read through the following documentation link
[[JDBC doc]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getIndexInfo(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean))

Also, read through these stackoverflow questions on the same topic

[[Question 1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358383/show-column-names-of-multiple-colum-index-via-jdbc) 
[[Question 2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059015/getindexinfo-returning-wrong-unique-columns-for-composite-primary-keys)
[[Question 3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001561/retrieve-all-indexes-for-a-given-table-with-jdbc)

What should I do to get this done via JDBC? One option I have is to have DB specific queries to get the list of indices and run them through JDBC (but I don't want to go that route)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fourth parameter for `getIndexInfo()` is

> `unique` - when true, return only indices for unique values; when false, return indices regardless of whether unique or not

As you are passing `true` for that parameter, only unique indexes are returned, but `myCompound1` is not defined as unique, so getIndexInfo() does not return it. You need to pase `false` for that parameter:

```
tableMeta.getIndexInfo(null, null, table, false, false);
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I overlooked that.